# Django migrate command fails with change in foreign key related name

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, django-models, django-migrations

I have a model with a foreign key field. I want to give the foreign key a related name. However, migration fails because of the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm using Django==1.10.5
Database backend is PostgreSQL

**models.py Before/After migrations**

Before:

```
class Contest_participants(models.Model):
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest)
```

After:

```
 class Contest_participants(models.Model):
     contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, related_name='contests')
```

The makemigrations command works fine, but the migrate command fails with the above noted error.

Complete Traceback Error:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying teams.0013_auto_20171031_1225...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 19, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 204, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 495, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 117, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 504, in _alter_field
    fk_names = self._constraint_names(model, [old_field.column], foreign_key=True)
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 931, in _constraint_names
    constraints = self.connection.introspection.get_constraints(cursor, model._meta.db_table)
  File "/home/aps/Documents/neuron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/introspection.py", line 178, in get_constraints
    "foreign_key": tuple(used_cols[0].split(".", 1)) if kind.lower() == "foreign key" else None,
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**EDIT:** Migrations

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('teams', '0012_auto_20170904_1524'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='contest_participants',
            name='contest',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='contests', to='contest.Contest'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: why u want to use related_names in Django model?

Comment: Add code from your migration file for this migration.

Comment: This might help https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25476

Comment: @AbiWaqas I want to use contest filed in admin.py for other app, without related name I am unable to access fileds in my Contest model as the django gives lookup error

Comment: Your code snippets don't provide enough information about the error. Also please structure your question better: first comes the code, then the error thrown. You jump from error to code changes, then again to error. Last but not least - follow the conventions and read PEP8. Class names are written in PascalCase, and in Django they are singular none, so it should be `ContestParticipant`.

Comment: If you can't name it you can't solve it. The `related_name` you chose -
 `contests` - shows that you don't understand the problem. Therefore you can't solve it. When you call `Contest.contests.all()` you'll get all participants for a contest, but that's not obvious from the code. You could better call the related name `contest_participants` or just `participants`. Then you'd have `Contest.participants.all()` getting all participants for a contest.

Comment: @cezar Thank you I will follow the question structure as mentioned. I usually follow PEP8, but I have just entered a new project which is created by someone else and is on production, so I can't just go on changing the names. I know there is a need of code refactoring. But it will be done gradually, can you tell how can I provide more information.

Comment: @cezar regarding the second comment I know what I am doing, and I don't want to use the field as Contest.contests.all(), I want it for some other purpose and as I said the code is written by someone else so you might be right and I have to look into it.